# Cleaning HexRays Output

Tags: ida, hexrays

My HexRays decompiler output often looks like:

```
  v0 = LoadLibraryW(L"wininet.dll");
  v1 = v0;
  if ( !v0 )
    goto LABEL_1;
  v2 = GetProcAddress(v0, "InternetOpenW");
  v3 = GetProcAddress(v1, "InternetConnectW");
  v4 = v2;
  v5 = v4;
```

To me, there's just a couple variables here.  v0, v2, and v3.  The rest are entirely duplicate.  Is it possible to clean up my decompiler output to eliminate these extraneous variables?

Answer (score 5):

Locate cursor at v1 and press <kbd>=</kbd> . If I remember it correctly since IDA 6.6 it will allow you to define that some variable is actually same as other.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from v6.6, IDA supports [decompiler API](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=107). The documentation is poor, almost non-existing. Yet, in theory, it should be possible to write a plugin to perform static analysis on the abstract syntax tree (AST) produced by the decompiler, thereby eliminating useless unit assignments.

Answer (score 0):

A brief tl;dr code sample on how to map, rename and re-type variables programmatically in python.

*edit: added code to set_lvar_type to allow usage of strings for types (took me ages to work that one out).  now you can do things like:*

```
mapping = [ 'accum', 'v7', 'v4', 'shift', 'v5', 'v6', 'ptr', 'v2', 'v3' ]
for n, x, y in chunk_tuple(mapping, 3):
    if map_lvar(x, y, ea) and              \
       set_lvar_type(y, 'int32_t', ea) and \
       rename_lvar(y, n, ea):
            print("set {}".format(n))
```

[image]

*just be aware that `int` as a type won't work, but `int32_t` will*

see [github](https://github.com/sfinktah/sfida/blob/main/hexrayfracker.py) for the rest of the code.  don't expect this to work on IDA 6.x, though maybe it will.  i've never tried.

```
import re
from itertools import islice

import ida_hexrays
import idaapi
import idautils
import idc


def map_lvar(src, dst, ea):
    func = idaapi.get_func(ea)
    if func:
        ea = func.start_ea
        vu = idaapi.open_pseudocode(ea, 0)

        lvars1 = [n for n in vu.cfunc.lvars if n.name == src]
        lvars2 = [n for n in vu.cfunc.lvars if n.name == dst]
        if len(lvars1) == 1 and len(lvars2) == 1:
            print("mapping {} to {}".format(lvars1[0].name, lvars2[0].name))
            # we might need to change the lvar type?
            vu.set_lvar_type(lvars1[0], lvars2[0].type())
            vu.map_lvar(lvars1[0], lvars2[0])
        else:
            print("couldn't find one of the vars {} or {}".format(src, dst))

def set_lvar_type(src, t, ea):
    if isinstance(t, str):
        type_tuple = idaapi.get_named_type(None, t, 1) 
        tif = idaapi.tinfo_t()
        tif.deserialize(None, type_tuple[1], type_tuple[2])
        if tif:
            t = tif
        else:
            print("couldn't convert {} into tinfo_t".format(t))
            return False

    func = idaapi.get_func(ea)
    if func:
        ea = func.start_ea
        vu = idaapi.open_pseudocode(ea, 0)
        if not vu:
            return False
        lvars = [n for n in vu.cfunc.lvars if n.name == src]
        if len(lvars) == 1:
            print("changing type of {} to {}".format(lvars[0].name, t))
            return vu.set_lvar_type(lvars[0], t)
        else:
            print("couldn't find var {}".format(src))
    return False

def rename_lvar(src, dst, ea):
    def make_unique_name(name, taken):
        if name not in taken:
            return name
        fmt = "%s_%%i" % name
        for i in range(3, 1024):
            tmpName = fmt % i
            if tmpName not in taken:
                return tmpName
        return "i_give_up"

    func = idaapi.get_func(ea)
    if func:
        ea = func.start_ea
        vu = idaapi.open_pseudocode(ea, 0)
        names = [n.name for n in vu.cfunc.lvars]
        if dst in names:
            dst = make_unique_name(dst, names)
        lvars = [n for n in vu.cfunc.lvars if n.name == src]
        if len(lvars) == 1:
            print("renaming {} to {}".format(lvars[0].name, dst))
            vu.rename_lvar(lvars[0], dst, 1)
            # how to close the view without a widget object?
            #     idautils.close_pseudocode (nope)
            #     ida_kerwin.close_widget   (nope)
        else:
            print("couldn't find var {}".format(src))
```